# What does an error of 50 after connect fails in Windows mean?

Tags: sockets

I'm trying out a multi-threaded server in C++.  The server can serve one client fine, but after the first client I cannot connect to the server.  When I call `WSAGetLastError()`, I get an return of `50`.  I can't seem to find the error code on MSDN's website, so I'm wondering if anyone else here, who's more experienced with C++ and the Socket API in Windows can tell me what this error means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error 50 means: *The network request is not supported*. Since you didn't post any code, it's not really easy to say something more specific.

Comment: Thanks.  I haven't touched that program in a while due to other things.  I'll go see what's wrong with it later.  I honestly don't see how the network request isn't supported but I'll go back and double-check my code and see if it there's something wrong with the commands that I'm sending and receiving.